# Google Analytics Enhanced Link Attribution Not Working

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm trying to use Google Analytics enhanced link attribution on my site -- https://nerdscorekeeper.azurewebsites.net

Normal in-page analytics are working just fine, but I need to use advanced link attribution because I have many links that point to the same page and I need to distinguish them. Per the following link, Google states that:

> If an element does not have a unique ID, then Analytics looks up to
>   three levels higher in the DOM structure for a unique ID (i.e., the
>   element's parent's parent)" :
>   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en&ref_topic=2558810

The links that have this problem all have a unique id at the parent or parent's parent level, but they still do not attribute correctly. Below is a screenshot demonstrating this not working:

[image]

I have Enhanced Link Attribution turned on on my Google Analytics property, and I have made the change to the tracking code as well to have:

```
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
```

Any idea what's missing here?

Comment: It appears to recognize that there are 3 different links.  It may be that there are so few clicks that it's not breaking them down.  Perhaps all you need is more data.  The specs also state pretty clearly that the numbers may be a bit "fuzzy".   My final thought is that the fact that the links do have ID may be throwing the system off.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JimEdelstein. Your point is fair. However, I just picked a wider date range on some more active components and I have the same result. All of the thumbs up / thumbs down icons on the home page of http://nemestats.com have the exact same number of clicks (177) and say that "this link + 9 more link to /". In regards to having and ID throwing the system off... geeze I hope not since the recommendation is to have an ID!